# R SF: SF point automatically transfered to List after IFELSE justification, how should I recover it?

Tags: r, geometry, r-sf

I am new to sf so I am not sure if this is a bug or I have done some unreasonable coding. Basically, I used to have a couple of sf object (which means if I code the `class(geometry)`, R will return me something like `"sfc_POINT" "sfc"`). However, as there are duplications within these data, I did an `Ifelse` justification for keeping the geometry of the eligible points, whereas setting the ineligible points to NA (so that I will assign a new geometry to these points by some algorithm in the future). However, after I have run the `ifelse` code, I found the class of my `geometry` column is automatically transformed to `list` and I cannot use it anymore for my future sf-related coding. I try to search online and cannot really find a way to transform these objects back to sf object.

You can find below code for a simple example of what I have done:

```
#Creating example sf object
DT <- data.frame(
        lat1=c(-26.3, -27.1, -26.8),
        long1=c(27.3, 28.5, 28.2),
        lat2=c(-26.5, -26.9, -27.2),
        long2=c(28.3, 27.5, 28.1))
DT$geometry <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(DT,coords = c("lat1","long1")))
class(DT$geometry)
#Now it is still "sfc_POINT" "sfc"

# Add some justification column for IFELSE
DT <- DT %>% 
  mutate(originDestinType = rep(c(0, 1), length.out = n()))

#I want to set the point with "1" in the originDestinType to NA so that 
#I can change it by some algorithm in the future
DT$geometry <- ifelse(DT$originDestinType == 0,
                      DT$geometry,
                      NA)

#But now the geometry column is changed to list, without geometry feature it used to have 
class(DT$geometry)
```

I am wondering if you have any tips for transferring the sf geometry back? Or if there is a better way to solve the functionalities that I would like to achieve (setting geometry to NA for some rows for future use)? Thanks very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Any reason why you can't change the order of what you're doing? I'd do the step of setting some geometries to `NA` before calling `st_geometry`. Otherwise, you might just need to cast it as a geometry again with `st_geometry`

Comment: Hello Camile, well it is because this is just an example data for this issue. In my real case, I didn't get the "initial" geometry by `st_geometry`, instead, it was obtained by a `left_join` from another dataframe. Also, I tried to code `st_geometry(DT$geometry)` in the example I given, and it says "no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "list"" :( Do you have any idea how to solve this? I will be much appreciate for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your request correctly, you only need to end your code with the following line:

`DT$geometry <- st_as_sfc(DT$geometry, crs = st_crs(4326))`

You only have to check the EPSG code (and if necessary, enter the one that suits you). For your information, here I have indicated the code corresponding to the WGS84 geographic coordinate system.

Comment: Hello Lovalery, yes this is the function that I am looking for :) Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Hello Jingjun, glad I could help you. I wish you all the best.